# Retain unmatched nodes in apply templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to sort records based on a field (account) only if the another field (depositvalue)is not blank. I am able to do this but my current xslt is removing unmatched nodes in apply templates. How can always leave everything else untouched in this case. The record to be sorted (DirectDeposit) may not always be there for some Employees.

I already made progress on the sorting.

XSLT:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' 
   xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <Employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DirectDeposit[not(depositvalue = '')]" >
            <xsl:sort select="account"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DirectDeposit[depositvalue = '']"/>
    </Employee>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

actual result: (employee header is gone)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Hire>
 <Employee>
 <DirectDeposit>
  <action>DirectDeposit</action>
  <created_by/>
  <created_on_timestamp>2018-07-13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
  <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
  <account>2</account>
  <depositvalue>200</depositvalue>
 </DirectDeposit>
 <DirectDeposit>
  <action>DirectDeposit</action>
  <created_by/>
  <created_on_timestamp>2018-07-13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
  <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
  <account>3</account>
  <depositvalue>100</depositvalue>
 </DirectDeposit>
 <DirectDeposit>
  <action>DirectDeposit</action>
  <created_by/>
  <created_on_timestamp>2018-07-13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
  <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
  <account>1</account>
  <depositvalue/>
 </DirectDeposit>
 </Employee>
  <Employee/>
  </Hire>
```

Expected:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Hire>
  <Employee>
    <Header>
        <action/>
        <created_by/>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-07- 
                 13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
        <AdditionalElements/>
         </Header>
        <DirectDeposit>
        <action>DirectDeposit</action>
        <created_by/>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-07- 
                   13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
        <account>2</account>
        <depositvalue>200</depositvalue>
       </DirectDeposit>
         <DirectDeposit>
        <action>DirectDeposit</action>
        <created_by/>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-07-13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
        <account>3</account>
        <depositvalue>100</depositvalue>
    </DirectDeposit>
    <DirectDeposit>
        <action>DirectDeposit</action>
        <created_by/>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-07-13T19:46:58.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        <date_of_birth>1985-04-09</date_of_birth>
        <account>1</account>
        <depositvalue/>
    </DirectDeposit>
</Employee>
<Employee/>
```

Comment: If you want the Header then add `<xsl:apply-templates select="Header"/>` before the other 2 `xsl:apply-templates` instructions. This is a guess, since I don't see your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`<xsl:apply-templates select="Header"/>`

to your `match="Employee"` template. If you don't process the Header element, it won't be processed, and will therefore be absent from the output.